# Send photo to the bank through onChange in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am converting the photo to base64 and displaying it on the console, but the value in useState does not update immediately. It only shows from the second attempt to upload the photo.

The first console.log shows null and the second shows the first uploaded photo and so on.

```
import React,{ useState } from 'react';

const Portfolio = () => {

  const[fotoPortifolio, setFotoPortifolio] = useState({
        foto: ""
    })

   function handleFoto(e){
  
      var file = e.target.files[0],
       reader = new FileReader();
           
      reader.onloadend = function () {
       var b64 = reader.result.replace(/^data:.+;base64,/, '');
        setFotoPortifolio({...fotoPortifolio,
         foto:  b64
        })};
           
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    addFoto()
}


   function addFoto() {    
  
        console.log(fotoPortifolio)

    }

  
  return (
        <>

        <input  name="foto" onChange={handleFoto} type='file' accept="image/png, image/jpeg"/>
               </>

    )
};
```

Comment: can you better format your code? and what's the empty `<>` html tag?

Comment: @BurningAlcohol - that's a React Fragment - https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question actually gets asked quite a lot! It's because the `setState` operation doesn't change the value until the next render. Changing a state property *will* trigger a re-render though - you can verify this by changing your code by getting rid of `addFoto` and instead using an effect as follows -

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(fotoPortifolio);
}, [fotoPortifolio]);
```

For more information, [check the documentation for setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) -

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.